# Ph.D. Reviewer complains: "(Syntax) Error in function definition"

Tags: functions, definition

Next week I will defend my Ph.D. thesis in the field of Scientific Visualization.
I have a question that is at the end related to syntax and personal preference, I think.

I use bold letters for vectorial values and small letters for scalars.
In my thesis, I introduce a space deformation function: $\mathbf{y}(\mathbf{x},t)$.
The function is defined in space-time, $\mathbf{x}$ defines a space-coordinate and $t$ a time-coordinate. The content of the function is not essential for my question, and I post it for completeness:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{y}(\mathbf{x},t) &= \mathbf{x} + \mu\mathbf{x_d} \hspace{9em}(1)\\
\mu &= \mu_s\mu_t  \hspace{10.2em}(2)\\
\mu_s &= (s_\mathbf{x}^3 + 3 s_\mathbf{x}^2(1-s_\mathbf{x}))  \hspace{5.3em}(3)\\
\mu_t &= (s_t^3 + 3 s_t^2(1-s_t))  \hspace{5.4em}(4)\\
r &= \| \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x_c}  \| \hspace{8.5em}(5)\\
s_\mathbf{x} &= \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
    1                      \hspace{2.5mm} & r<r_1                \hspace{5mm} \\
    \frac{r-r_2}{r_1-r_2}  \hspace{2.5mm} & r_1 \leq r  \leq r_2 \hspace{5mm} \\
    0                      \hspace{2.5mm} & r>r_2                \hspace{5mm} \\
  \end{array} \right. \hspace{2.2em}(6)\\
%%
  s_t &= \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
    1-  \frac{|t-t_c|}{r_t}  \hspace{2.5mm} & |t-t_c|<r_t \hspace{5mm}  \\
    0                        \hspace{2.5mm} & \mbox{else} \hspace{5mm}. \\
  \end{array} \right.  \hspace{0.2em}(7)\\
\end{align}
$$

The values for $\mathbf{x_d}, \mathbf{x_c}, t_c, r_1, r_2$ are fixed and get selected by the user. Inside a circular area defined by $r_1$ and $r_2$ at position $(\mathbf{x_c}, t)$ [in space-time] locations get translated in direction $\mathbf{x_d}$. The translation is defined by $\mathbf{y}(\mathbf{x},t)$ and depends on position $\mathbf{x}$ and time $t$.

One of my reviewers complains, that "... function $(1)$ only defines a spatial mapping and ignores the temporal component." I do not agree here. In my opinion the temporal component is defined with $\mu$ and therefore by combination of equations $(1), (2), (4)$ and $(7)$.

I see three possibilities:

1. Either I have a syntactical error in $(1)$,
2. my reviewer did not entirely understand what happens,
3. or I did not define the temporal component 'clean enough' and the function is indeed flawed.

---

I would be glad to get some other opinions here.

**Questions:**

1. Can you see an (obvious) mistake I cannot see?
2. Is there some kind of 'rule' that demands that $t$ has to appear at the right-hand-side of equation $(1)$?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just add a clarification? Something like "Note that the temporal behavior is encoded in $\mu(t)$.

Comment: If the reviewer is one of the testing teachers then don't make much trouble: add whatever (s)he wants and go to get your PhD. In these very small, unimportant matters it is better to be wise than to be right...

Comment: @user619894 Right! As a general rule of thumb, if a reviewer thinks you've got something wrong, and you think you've got it right, you might be right or you might be wrong, but it's certain that you've not explained yourself well enough.

Comment: Why not replace the bare $\,\mu\,$ with $\,\mu_{s,t}$?

Comment: Next week I will have to defend my thesis and give a presentation. I have no personal contact to this reviewer. If there *is* a mistake I will fix it for sure. Currently I am not sure if there is a 'hard' mistake or if it is enough to clarify what I mean, e.g. "Note that the temporal component is contained in $\mu$".

Comment: @Somos: This would be a valid option in my opinion.

Comment: @user619894: This might already solve the problem.

Comment: @DonAntonio and Mathmo123: I completely agree. It is not my intention to be right - I want to be wise :) I am preparing my presentation and want to include some suggestions to clarify/fix the problem.

Comment: Could it be that the reviewer wants you to formally define $\mathbf{y}$ as a $(\mathbf{x},t) \mapsto (\mathbf{x'},t')$ transformation rather than just $(\mathbf{x},t) \mapsto \mathbf{x'}$, even though $t'$ is simply $t$?

Comment: @user3733558: Mmmmhhhh that is a good thought I did not think about yet. Indeed my function only transforms $\mathbf{x}$ to $\mathbf{x}'$ and $t$ stays the same. This justifies the term that I 'ignore' the $t$-component in my transformation. This could be the solution and I should think about if this is even possible somehow. Boah!!! I feel 'operationally blind' (betriebsblind). Oh my god... this brings up many new questions!